# Nginx secure_link return 403 if filename has symbol characters

Tags: php, nginx

This is the php code i'm using for generate secure link:

```
$file = /dl/file.rar;
$uri_prefix = "example.com";
$secret_word = "my_secret";
$time = time()+86400;
$md5 = base64_encode(md5($secret_word.$file.$time, true));
$md5 = strtr($md5, '+/', '-_');
$md5 = str_replace('=', '', $md5);
$url= $uri_prefix.$file.'?key='.$md5.'&e='.$time;
```

And my nginx.conf is:

```
location ~\.(mkv|zip|MP4|Mp4|mp4|rar)$ {
        secure_link $arg_key,$arg_e;
        secure_link_md5 "my_secret$arg_e";

        if ($secure_link = "") {
                return 403;
        }
        if ($secure_link = 0) {
                return 410;
        }
        limit_rate_after 8m;
        limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 2;
        limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=5 nodelay;
        limit_rate 600k;
}
```

its work fine but if file name has symbol characters like `()` Nginx return 403; why ?
**filename example** 
`this.is.file.name.(short-text).rar`

Comment: Try to urlencode filename before calculating md5

Comment: @AlexeyTen I tried it but did not work, i'm replace `(` with `%28` and `)` with `%29` too but result not changed

Comment: Why do you remove `=`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen actually I found this code by searching,i don't know

Comment: so was this solved?

Answer (score -2):

According to the NGINX community "if is evil" and shouldn't be used.
[IF is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)

You may wish to look into [lua/OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/) for this type of thing.

OpenResty leverages LUA scripting on top of NGINX, and in many cases will fill a lot of gaps.